# My method returns the same value for each value in the returned array

Tags: java, arrays

So.. In my program I have built a method which takes two values from an array and multiply them and after  that it has to hold the value into an array.Then I do this again, but instead of saving the second value in the next array position it seems to save it on every position.I think something with my loop in the method is really wrong.I want every computed value to be saved in the array ( at least thats the point ) and in the end to print them out ? Right now the program prints out this:

4200
4200
4200
4200
4200
4200

Any help would be appreciated.Im new in Java.

```
public class TestingN
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            int [] initialMarks = new int [4];
            int [] result = new int [2];
            initialMarks[0] = 40;
            initialMarks[1] = 60;
            initialMarks[2] = 60;
            initialMarks[3] = 70;
            result = computedMarks(initialMarks[0], initialMarks[1]);
            result = computedMarks(initialMarks[2], initialMarks[3]);
            for(int i=0; i< result.length; i++)
                  System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
            public static int [] computedMarks(int mark1, int mark2) 
          { 
                int [] i= new int [6];
                for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++)
                {                   
                    if ((mark1 < 35 && mark2 > 35) || (mark1 > 35 && mark2 < 35))
                    {
                        i[j] = 35;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i[j] = (mark1 * mark2);
                    }
                }
              return i;
          }
}
```

Comment: result = computedMarks(initialMarks[2], initialMarks[3]); is simply overwriting the results of the previous computation using initialMarks[0] and initialMarks[1]. Perhaps you want/need result[0] = blah blah blah and result[1] = blah blah blah?

Comment: Uhm, when I add [0] and [1] to result it starts having converting issues ( cannot convert from int [] to int ) and asks me to change the method output type, but i need it to be array... :(

Comment: How can I repair that loop ?

Comment: computedMarks fills up a table with the same value. Its either 35, or the product of mark1 and mark2. What do you try to achieve with this program?

Comment: The test ((mark1 < 35 && mark2 > 35) || (mark1 > 35 && mark2 < 35)) always fail: you don't have a value lower than 35 in your test. Only mark1*mark2 occurs and since you overwrite first call to computedMarks you have only 60*70=4200 in your result.

Comment: In computedMark, value computed in the loop are constant for a given call! Here your loop seems to be unless or you did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , this should work. You dont need to have an array on the method computedMarks

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
                int [] initialMarks = new int [4];
                int [] result = new int [2];
                initialMarks[0] = 40;
                initialMarks[1] = 60;
                initialMarks[2] = 60;
                initialMarks[3] = 70;
                result[0] = computedMarks(initialMarks[0], initialMarks[1]);
                result[1] = computedMarks(initialMarks[2], initialMarks[3]);
                for(int i=0; i< result.length; i++){
                    System.out.println(result[i]);
                }

  } public static int computedMarks(int mark1, int mark2) 
  { 
      int i = 0;
      {                   
          if ((mark1 < 35 && mark2 > 35) || (mark1 > 35 && mark2 < 35))
          {
              i = 35;
          }
          else
          {
              i = (mark1 * mark2);
          }
      }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code (  result = computedMarks(initialMarks[0], initialMarks[1]);)as below

```
 result[0] = computedMarks(initialMarks[0], initialMarks[1])[0];
 result[1] = computedMarks(initialMarks[2], initialMarks[3])[0];
```

Comment: thank you man, that is what i needed. I know i can change the method to return just  an INT but i have to make it return an array thats how they want it in my school and im stuck now and really really thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((mark1 < 35 && mark2 > 35) || (mark1 > 35 && mark2 < 35))
```

This will always be false with the value set

```
        initialMarks[0] = 40;
        initialMarks[1] = 60;
        initialMarks[2] = 60;
        initialMarks[3] = 70;
```

So the `else` clause will be the only executed line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are overwriting your `result` variable by using

```
        result = computedMarks(initialMarks[0], initialMarks[1]);
        result = computedMarks(initialMarks[2], initialMarks[3]);
```

That way your first `computedMarks` call will be erased by the second call. If you want to see both results you could use this code:

```
        result = computedMarks(initialMarks[0], initialMarks[1]);
        for(int i=0; i< result.length; i++)
        System.out.println(result[i]);

        result = computedMarks(initialMarks[2], initialMarks[3]);
        for(int i=0; i< result.length; i++)
        System.out.println(result[i]);
```

Second, you are creating a 2 cells array at the beginning of the main but in `computedMarks` there is a `new int [6]` statement. The output of the program is that 6-cells array with the values of `60` and `70` multiplied 6 times by this sentence:

```
} else {
    i[j] = (mark1 * mark2);
}
```

It always enter in the `else` part because the arguments are `60` and `70`, which never fullfills `if ((mark1 < 35 && mark2 > 35) || (mark1 > 35 && mark2 < 35))`.

So at the end you got `60 * 70` in each cell of the 6-cells array.